# Does removing all observers also disable keeySynced()

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to keep a part of my database synced, but only need an actual callback when a certain view is loaded. When the view loads I'm calling:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("data").observe(.childAdded...
```

then when the view exits I want to call

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("data").removeAllObservers()
```

Elsewhere in my app I'm calling:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("data").keepSynced(true)
```

I know that `keepSynced()` simply adds an observer to the ref, so when I call `removeAllObservers()` will it cancel out the `keepSynced(true)`?

Answer (score 1):

No, calling `keepSynced(true)` means that the actual data on the device will be kept in sync with Firebase servers.

This means that when you do eventually add a listener to that location, you will be able to very quickly retrieve the data, because the device has been keeping it in sync for you for a while.

The only way to disable the syncing is to call `keepSynced(false)`.